# Javascript closure, function always points to the last object in array

Tags: javascript, closures

Hello everyone I have following code

```
POINT = function () {
    that = {};
    that.x = 0; that.y = 0;

    that.setPoint = function (x, y) {
        that.x = x;
        that.y = y;
    };

    that.toString = function () {
        return that.x + ',' + that.y + ' ';
    };    

    return that;
};

PEN = function () {
    var that = {};
    var points = [];
    var buffer_size = 5, head = -1, length = 0;

    // Init buffer
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer_size; i++) {
        points.push(POINT());
    }

    that.addPoint = function (x, y) {
        head = (head + 1) % buffer_size;
        points[head].setPoint(x, y);
        if (length < buffer_size) {length++;}
    };

    that.toString = function (path) {
        var d = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var index = (head - i) < 0 ? buffer_size + (head - i) : (head - i);
            d += points[index].toString();
        }
        return d;
    };

    return that;
};

// Initialization
var i = 0, pen = PEN();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pen.addPoint(i + 1, i + 1);
}

alert(pen.toString()); // RESULT 10,10 10,10 10,10 10,10 10,10
```

The `points` array is filled with correct `pen` objects, but the function `setPoint` always points to the last `pen` object in the `points` array.

NOTE: I want to have `x` and `y` coordinate directly accessible, thus i am not declaring `x` and `y` as a "local" variables using var.

The fiddle with example is found here: http://jsfiddle.net/DNVjy/2/

Comment: `that` in `POINT` is global, add `var that = {};`.

Comment: BTW, why emulate a ring buffer, when you could just do `points.shift()` to remove the 0th element?

Comment: @Alnitak I need the ring buffer for code speed purposes. As I understood the `points.shift()` function would remove point from `points` array, thus there is potential problem with memory allocation when lot of points will be added periodically.

Comment: @OndřejSevera I'm not aware of any particular risks with memory allocation.  I suspect the overhead of calculating the current ring buffer offset might be more than calling `.shift()` each time the buffer fills up.

Comment: @Alnitak So if I understand it well, for me it is better to use `Array.push()` and `Array.shift()` if array exceeds the buffer capacity? I thought that these operations will have overhead in memory management.

Comment: no, I'm saying it _might_ be better.  It depends on how frequently you're reading the array vs updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `that` in `POINT` shouldn't be global!  You're overwriting the same global variable every time you create one, so they all refer to the same pair of values.

FWIW, why not use JS objects the way they were intended?

```
function POINT() {
    if (this instanceof POINT) {
        this.x = 0; this.y = 0;
    } else {
        return new POINT();   // allow creation without "new"
    }
};

POINT.prototype.setPoint = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

POINT.prototype.toString = function () {
     return this.x + ',' + this.y + ' ';
};
```

The module pattern you're using is sub-optimal for many purposes:

- each instance gets its own copy of the methods, instead of sharing them
- the objects returned have no specific "type"

Comment: I think it's *crockford's constructor pattern*. If it is, `new` is not required.

Comment: @Yoshi yes, I recall seeing it in Yahoo's code now.  I don't like it.  It's OK for some object types, but for objects that are instantiated lots of times its wasteful because every instance gets its own copy of the methods on the object.

Comment: You're right of course. Didn't want to comment on whether to use it or not. Just that it might be, that the OP is using it, and if so, it's in someway ok to not use `this` and `new` (like every answer is suggesting).

Comment: Thank you for such a fast response, @Yoshi is right, i am using _Crockford's pattern_. I gives me all benefits from prototypal inheritance. I only make rookie mistake, that I didn't use _var_ in front of that :(

Answer (score 3):

You should put your vars onto a var :-)

Right now you are defining the functions and the local 'that' on the window object. There is no need for 'that' as the code is now.

Try this:

```
function POINT() {

    this.x = 0; this.y = 0;

    this.setPoint = function (x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };

    this.toString = function () {
        return this.x + ',' + this.y + ' ';
    };    

    return this;
};

function PEN() {
    var points = [];
    var buffer_size = 5, head = -1, length = 0;

    // Init buffer
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer_size; i++) {
        points.push(new POINT());
    }

    this.addPoint = function (x, y) {
        head = (head + 1) % buffer_size;
        points[head].setPoint(x, y);
        if (length < buffer_size) {length++;}
    };

    this.toString = function (path) {
        var d = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var index = (head - i) < 0 ? buffer_size + (head - i) : (head - i);
            d += points[index].toString();
        }
        return d;
    };

    return this;
};
```

You now declare a pen like this:

```
var pen = new PEN();
```

(also notice `new POINT()` keyword inside the PEN "class").

Answer (score 2):

Changing `that` in `POINT` to local variable (place `var` in front of it) changes the output to:
`10,10 9,9 8,8 7,7 6,6`

Hopefully this is what you've been expecting. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DNVjy/3/